# Output and append print command to csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, netcdf4

I would like to read several variables from netCDF files and output them in a csv file.

The netCDF files are named as follow `surfclim_a` `surfclim_b`.

Several variables are included inside those files. I would like to pick up inside each files 2 variables named `Mlail` and `Mlaih` and append them into one single csv file.

For that i did the following code:

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import os
import numpy as np
import csv
stations = ["a", "b"]
inbasedir = "/home/david/test_pals/PALS/sites/"
varname = "surfclim_"
for station in stations:
    os.chdir(inbasedir)
    data = Dataset( varname + station + ".nc")
    lail = (data.variables['Mlail'][:])
    laih = (data.variables['Mlaih'][:])
    a = (station + "_Lail,", lail)
    b = (station + "_Laih,", laih)
    table = a + b
    print (table)
    with open ('LAI.csv', 'w') as ofile:
        writer = csv.writer(ofile)
        [writer.writerow(r) for r in table]
```

It output a table but instead of appending the value of each stations, I am currently just overwritting each results.

Moreover, the output file is not what I expected:
`b,_,L,a,i,l,","
[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]],[[ 0.0999756]]`

Does anyone has any hints or solution for me in order to:

- append the results instead of overwriting them,
- correctly place the comas `b_Lail` instead of `b,_,L,a,i,l,","`
- removing the brackets around the numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can simply open the csv file with `'a'` instead of `'w'` to append instead of overwriting.

2) The `writer.writerow` function expects an iterable, so when `r` is your station name, it treats the string a an iterable of characters.

3) I wasn't able to reproduce your bracket problem, but may be you could simply convert the array to a list? (With `lail = list(lail)`)

Also, to have a correctly formatted csv file, I guess you want the station/variable name on the same line as the list of values, no? (Assuming all arrays have the same size and are 1-D)

Finally, you can use the  `writer.writerows()` function. With my suggestions, your for loop could become:

```
for station in stations:
    os.chdir(inbasedir)
    data = Dataset( varname + station + ".nc")
    lail = data.variables['Mlail'][:]
    laih = data.variables['Mlaih'][:]
    table = [[station + "_Lail", *lail],
             [station + "_Laih", *laih]]
    with open('LAI.csv', 'a') as ofile:
        writer = csv.writer(ofile)
        writer.writerows(table)
```

Here I used starred unpacking of `lail` and `laih` so that each element of `table` is a list which first element in the station/variable name and all the others are the values.

Bonus :You might also want to write them in columns by appending everything to the table and transposing it before writing it to file. (This is a more proper way to format csv file IMHO, still assumes 1D and same size for all arrays).

```
table = []
for station in stations:
    os.chdir(inbasedir)
    data = Dataset( varname + station + ".nc")
    lail = data.variables['Mlail'][:]
    laih = data.variables['Mlaih'][:]
    table.append([station + "_Lail", *lail])
    table.append([station + "_Laih", *laih])

table_t = list(map(list, zip(*table)))  # Transposes the table
with open('LAI.csv', 'w') as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    writer.writerows(table_t)
```